# User login credentials used for file encryption

Tags: cryptography, aes, file-encryption

A system I'm implementing requires a user to create a single user, with a single login password.

I want to have a single password for the system, and not require multiple different password entries in order to encrypt/decrypt files after login in (the main purpose of this system).

The way I've implemented this is: when the user first setups on the account password,

- the password is hashed (bcrypted) *
- a salt is generated *
- a crypto key is generated using PBKDF2 (based on the salt)
- 256 random bits are generated
- the 256 bits are encrypted with the key derived using PBKDF2 *

All of the above "*" information is stored in a database

The decrypted 256 bits are used for the actual file encryption/decryption.

The reason I'm doing it this way, is if the single user decides to change his password, the files will still be decryptable (i just have to re-encrypt the random 256 bits with the new password).

Is this a common and secure approach?

Comment: Is this a webservice where the encrypted info lives on your server?

Comment: The encrypted files are stored in the cloud, the encrypted crypto key (256 bits) is stored in database

Comment: Yes it's a common approach.

Comment: What do you do when the user *forgets* their password? It's okay if the answer is "well, then their files are rendered inaccessible", but it should be a conscious decision.

Comment: ^ yup, that's what I was gonna ask.

Comment: Also, I'm sure I don't have to tell you to make sure you encrypt the data on it's way down (ie. https).

Comment: Your 2nd step and mention of salt in the 3rd step is confusing in the context of the other steps.  Can you clarify these please?

Comment: Im storing the password hash using bcrypt, for the actual crypto key I'm using PBKDF2, which requires a salt.

Comment: Bcrypt uses a salt too, but you didn't specifically mention that so I was confused why you mentioned it for PBKDF2.  I wanted to see if you were using the salt by itself for generating a key.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you use the result from bcrypt along with a salt to generate the key with PBKDF2. Since you are storing bcrypt result and salt, whats to stop someone who knows both to generate same key? I believe you are missing a step. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I'm using the plaintext password to generate the encryption key using PBKDF2, im not using the bcrypt output to generate the key.

The bcrypt hash is only used to verify that the correct password is provided. The PBKDF2 is used to then generate a key to encrypt/decrypt the 256 bits used for file encryption

Comment: In that case I don't see problems in your approach. It is a common approach.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is a workable approach. A few issues string to my mind, though.

1. You should salt the *bcrypt* hash as well, not just the *PBKDF2* function
2. You should not use the random 256 bits directly as an encryption key (unless you know exactly how your RNG works and always will work in all future versions). Use that random data as an input material to a proper key derivation function (like HKDF) instead.

Comment: I don't agree on your second and third point. There is nothing wrong in using PRNG for key generation as long as it is CSPRNG. Actually, it is a preferred way of generating symmetric keys. HKDFs are used when you want to expand low entropy material to a cryptographically sound key.
As for PBKDF2, if the output of PBKDF2 is used as an encryption key, once you change the password you will need to decrypt and encrypt all of the files again. I believe author is correct is his design. Similar design is used in DPAPI for example.

Comment: As I said, using the RNG data is fine, if you know which PRNG is implemented and thus can be sure that the output is not biased. The problem is, that most of the time, developers don't know that and just use some generic *GetRandom()* function. Using HKDF (or just a single HMAC call) afterwards, gives you an addition safety net. You are correct about the second part. I misread the question, and beleived that he is reencryptng the data upon password change anyway with a new 256-Bit key. I'll remove that part from my answer.